# Not working properly. What am I missing?

Tags: c, argv

the program is still very empty and "naked" because im just trying to get the logic out of the way before I actually start making functions. For some reason, whatever my argv[1] is, it always prints "The help message". What am I missing? I have a bad feeling about that for statement, but I dont know whats wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void help()
{
    printf("The help message\n");
    exit(1);
}

void a()
{
    printf("The a screen\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char recognised_commands[3] = {help(), a()};
    int i;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage of sake: \"sake [option(s)]\"\nFor a full listing of all available commands type \"-help\" or \"--help\"\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = recognised_commands[0]; i != recognised_commands; i++)
    {
        printf(argv[1]);
    }
}
```

Edit 1: djikay: Fixed the -1 to 0,
Ricky: How do I correct the help() and the a() to only call the one the user inputs after the program name (EX: sake -a)? I also fixed the exit(0). Thanks

Comment: Please tell me the `-1` in this is a typo: `recognised_commands[-1]`.

Comment: This: `char recognised_commands[3] = {help(), a()};` seems to be trying to assign the return value of `help()`, but the `help()` function doesn't return anything, it just prints a message.

Comment: There's quite some work on the `for` loop...

Comment: Turn up your compiler error level and pay attention to what it says... you should get several errors for this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char recognised_commands[3] = {help(), a()};
```

This line is definitely your issue. `help()` and `a()` are both being called, thus exiting your program.

Why are you trying to assign those function return values there? Both of the functions are `void` in return type, meaning they won't return anything anyways.

On a side note, calling exit() with 0 as the argument means your program exited without errors. I'd exit with 1 if it's because of an error (or even better, EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE, respectively).

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
char recognised_commands[3] = {help(), a()};
```

causes both `help` and `a` to be called.  `help` is called first, and it prints out the help message & exits the program.

Comment: This must generate a compilation error, so it should not cause `help` to be called, etc.